# Trying to grab the ID of deleted DB object in an event

Tags: php, eloquent, lumen

I am building an API with Lumen, and this particular part of my application contains the following relationships:

Promotions hasMany Items
Items hasMany images

On an image upload, a row is inserted which provides the URL to the uploaded image. The image is uploaded to public/assets/promotion_$id/item_$id.

When an item is deleted, so too does its respective image folder. That part was relatively easy, and can be done from inside my PromotionController:

```
public function delete_item(Request $request)
{
    $item = PromotionItems::find($request->input('id'))->toArray();
    $img_folder_path = 'assets/promotions/promotion_' . $item['promotion_id'] . '/item_' . $item['id'];

        if(is_dir($img_folder_path))
        {
            $files = array_diff(scandir($img_folder_path), array('.','..')); 
            foreach ($files as $file) 
            { 
              unlink($img_folder_path . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            rmdir($img_folder_path); 
        }

        $delete = PromotionItems::destroy($request->input('id'));
        return response()->json($delete);
}
```

This is okay, but this also needs to happen when a promotion is deleted. Right now, when a promotion is deleted, an event is called that also deletes items. When an item is deleted, an event is called that also deletes the image rows in the database. So it's a nice, neat chain of events.

But, it will only delete the image folder if an item is being deleted directly, which is why I would like to put this code in my delete event in my item model:

```
protected static function boot() 
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($item) 
        {

            $item->images()->delete();
        });
    }
```

However, this function's scope doesn't appear to extend to the actual object that's being deleted. And since the image path contains IDs, I need access to the item's properties before it's deleted.

I'm relatively new to Laravel/Lumen/Eloquent, so any advice would be appreciated.

Edit: I'm aware that I could technically put the folder delete code inside my Promotion controller in its delete function, and just call all the items and loop through them, deleting all their folders/files. But that's redundant code and I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that I'd have to do a folder delete on promotion delete anyway, because I'll want to delete its top level directory. So I just did a sort of recursive function in my controller:

```
public function remove_directory($path)
    {
        if(is_dir($path))
        {
            $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.','..')); 
            foreach ($files as $file) 
            { 
              (is_dir("$path/$file")) ? $this->remove_directory("$path/$file") : unlink($path . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            rmdir($path); 
        }
    }
```

So when I call it from my delete_promotion function, it deletes the promotion folder and all folders/files inside of it. And I just call the same function but with the /item_$id on the path in my delete_item function.